# Redirect to file, including current prompt line

Tags: io-redirection

How to include the redirected command itself to the output file redirection? For example

```
echo "hello!">output.txt
```

I want the content of output file like this:

```
echo "hello!">output.txt
hello!
```

Comment: Do you have a specific need for this?

Comment: Yes. I have a specific need. I am creating a log file.

Answer (score 13):

You may want one of two things here.

1. Using [`tee`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html) to get the result of the `echo` sent to the terminal as well as to the file:

   ```
   $ echo 'hello!' | tee output
   hello!
   $ cat output
   hello!
   ```
2. Using `script` to capture the whole terminal session:

   ```
   $ script
   Script started, output file is typescript
   $ echo 'hello!' >output
   $ cat output
   hello!
   $ exit
   Script done, output file is typescript
   ```

   ```
   $ cat typescript
   Script started on Sat Nov 10 15:15:06 2018
   $ echo 'hello!' >output
   $ cat output
   hello!
   $ exit

   Script done on Sat Nov 10 15:15:37 2018
   ```

If this is not what you are asking for, then please clarify your question.

Comment: Hi! Nanda, Thanks. I know tee. But I want the output file to include the redirect command that we type in, to be in the output file as well. When I do "cat output", I want to see "echo 'helo'>output" before the line "helo". Hope you understood.

Comment: @mandrake00 isn't that exactly what option 2 gives you? `script` should do what you need.

Comment: Thank you. The typescript output file has many unwanted lines such as "script started at ..." and "<cr><cr> etc. I was looking for a simple method so that when I do { echo 'helo'>out.txt } this would give a file with just 2 lines, i.e. {  echo 'helo'>out.txt  \n helo }

Comment: Do you want this to happen for every single command you ever type in any terminal? Just for specific commands? Please edit your question and give us more specific requirements.

Comment: some commands like  echo 'helo'>{option x} out.txt

Comment: Not for every commands. Just for a specific redirect command within a shell script.

Comment: You can suppress the lines about when it was started and stopped by using `script -q`

Answer (score 5):

In the genearality you're asking for, this is not possible.

To achieve this with additional tools (akin to `script`(1)), it would be necessary for that program, observing your shell, that in

```
command >foo
```

`foo` is the name of a file, and create it.  Also, the shell would try to create it, so there's conflict already.  Also, what if the program would print

```
command >foo
```

to the terminal?

From inside the shell, well, the shell's redirection process is extremely primitive from a programming point of view (try to find a C lecture where they build a primitive shell themselves, it is really surprising).

If you really need this, you would have to hack your own shell to intercept redirections and pass the command into the target file.  But there are probably a lot of nasty issues in the details...

Answer (score 5):

You can also pipe the whole shell:

```
$ sh -i |& tee sh.log
sh-4.4$ hello
sh: hello: command not found
sh-4.4$ echo hi
hi
sh-4.4$ exit
```

`-i` is needed to keep the shell interactive despite stdout not being a terminal. bash and zsh also support that option. `|&` pipes stdout and stderr; it works with zsh and bash, but not sh (there, you'd need `2>&1 |`). Of course, you could also use `&>` or `2>&1 >` if you just want to redirect to a file and nothing more. Anyways, `sh.log` here contains everything.

```
$ cat sh.log
sh-4.4$ hello
sh: hello: command not found
sh-4.4$ echo hi
hi
sh-4.4$ exit
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's acceptable for you to drop the output filename, I think the following is the easiest way:

```
command='echo "hello!"'
(echo "$command"; eval "$command") >output.txt
```

But if you need to print the filename then you could use the following:

```
command='echo "hello!"'
(echo "$command >output.txt"; eval "$command") >output.txt
```

You can introduce a variable for the filename in order to make sure that it is the same in the two occurrences:

```
output="output.txt"
command='echo "hello!"'
(echo "$command >$output"; eval "$command") >$output
```

This way you avoid the risk of having a difference in the printed filename and the actual filename.

Comment: Generalizing as a function: `f(){ command="$1"; file="$2"; (printf '%s >%s' "$command" "$file"; eval "$command") >"$file"; }` Then call: `f 'echo "Hello!"' output.txt`